# How to solve equations in Gaussian integers modulo p

Tags: equation-solving, complex, number-theory, big-numbers

How to solve a complex equation of the form:

$$z^n \equiv i \pmod p$$

where $z$ is a Gaussian integer, $i$ is the imaginary number, $n, p \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $p$ is prime.

I am dealing with quite big numbers, for example:
$z^{8192} \equiv i~\pmod {2^{61}-1}$.
This is just an example, i.e. $p$ need not be a Mersenne prime.

I tried the binomial expansion of $z^n=(a+bi)^n$ and solving the real and imaginary parts individually, but it takes a very long time (it's been 4 hours and *Mathematica* hasn't solved for the real part yet).

I tried this code:

```
Clear[z, n, p, a, b, r, t, eq1, eq2, system];
z = a + b*I;
n = 4096;
p = 18446744069414584321;
exp = Expand[z^n];
r = Expand[Re[exp]];
t = Expand[Im[exp]];
eq1 = Refine[r, a ∈ Integers && b ∈ Integers];
eq2 = Refine[t, a ∈ Integers && b ∈ Integers];
system = eq1 == 0 && eq2 == 1;
sol1 = Solve[system, {a, b}, Modulus -> p]
```

This code is very slow for big numbers. Any suggestions to improve it?

Comment: Have you tried it for small numbers? What code have you tried?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do that has you computing such huge modular roots?

Comment: I need to verify that the discrete Galois transform can work with the prime number indicated above. I tried the transform with small primes $(257, 8191)$ and small $(n=2)$. It worked fine. Now I need to use it in larger settings shown above for $(n=4k, 8k, 16k, 32k, 64k)$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a rather naïve implementation; I'm sure there are more clever/efficient approaches:

```
modRoot[z_, {p_Integer?PrimeQ, r_Integer?Positive}, m_Integer?PrimeQ] := 
   Nest[Select[Union[Flatten[(\[FormalX] + I \[FormalY] /. 
               Solve[{Sum[(-1)^j Binomial[p, 2 j] \[FormalX]^(p - 2 j)
                          \[FormalY]^(2 j), {j, 0, Quotient[p, 2]}] == Re[#], 
                      Sum[(-1)^j Binomial[p, 2 j + 1] \[FormalX]^(p - 2 j - 1)
                          \[FormalY]^(2 j + 1), {j, 0, Quotient[p - 1, 2]}] ==
                      Im[#]},
                     {\[FormalX], \[FormalY]}, Modulus -> m]) & /@ #]], NumberQ] &, z, r]

gaussianPowerModList[z_, r_Rational, m_Integer?PrimeQ] := 
        Fold[modRoot[#, #2, m] &,
             {PowerMod[z, Numerator[r], m]}, FactorInteger[Denominator[r]]]
```

It takes a while on your particular example:

```
AbsoluteTiming[sols = gaussianPowerModList[I, 1/2^13, 2^61 - 1];]
   {521.019, Null}

Length[sols]
   8192

Take[sols, 3]
   {146709914666800 + 1089528222731080675 I, 
    403020492323839 + 87412432372606530 I, 
    1417152643549164 + 256379023454276512 I}

PowerMod[%, 2^13, 2^61 - 1]
   {I, I, I}
```

---

A slightly less difficult example:

```
gaussianPowerModList[1 - I, 1/(2 3 5), 2^19 - 1]
   {26299 + 165240 I, 68075 + 434841 I, 94374 + 75794 I, 429913 + 448493 I,
    456212 + 89446 I, 497988 + 359047 I}

PowerMod[%, 2 3 5, 2^19 - 1]
   {1 - I, 1 - I, 1 - I, 1 - I, 1 - I, 1 - I}
```

Comment: Calling the function 

    sols1 = gaussianPowerModList[I, 8192, 18446744069414584321];]

runs out of memory after more than 10 hours of execution.
Is there any way it can be computed more efficiently?

Comment: You'll notice that you get exactly 8192 roots since you have a prime modulus. Do you really need all those 8192 roots? If so, you could modify the method here so that they are computed a few at a time instead of in a single blow.

Comment: I need only a single root. But I have no idea how to instruct solve to exit after finding a single solution?

Comment: "I need only a single root." - you really ought to have mentioned that in your question to begin with. :|

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention that @J.M.. One strange thing is: why it computes the roots modulo $(2^{61}-1)$ fast while working with that prime is very slow and requires large memory?

Comment: I don't really know; I'm not familiar with what algorithm `Solve[]` is using under the hood to solve modular equations.

Comment: ♦ could it relate to the following: the prime I am using is $\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ while Merssene primes such as $2^{61}-1$ are $\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$. These primes are also primes in the Gaussian integer domain. Could it be that there are no solutions at all for the non-Merssene prime I'm using?

Answer (score 1):

Since $p$ is prime, this equation only needs to be solved within finite field. Depending on $p$, if $p \equiv 1 \space mod \space 4$, then $\sqrt{-1}$ has good reduction on $\mathbb{F_p}$, gaussian integers are not needed. Otherwise $\sqrt{-1}$ exists in $\mathbb{F_{p^2}}$. A general method would be finding discrete logarithm in respective finite field, then solving linear congruence $log(z^n) \space\equiv\space n log(z)$in either $\mathbb{Z/(p-1)Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z/(p^2-1)Z}$. Index calculus algorithm can be used to crack discrete logarithm over finite field, with subexponential complexity wrt. $log(p)$.

---

Mathematica don't come with strong utilities dealing finite fields. `Mod` and `PowerMod` both work with gaussian integers. `PowerMod` with rational arguments can be used to find roots modulo integers. However it won't work well with fields extensions. (Bug?)

```
In[1]:= PowerMod[2,1/8192,2^61-1]                                                                                                                                                                                                               

Out[1]= 2305843009213562879

In[2]:= PowerMod[I, 1/8192,2^61-1]                                                                                                                                                                                                              

Algebra`PolynomialRemainderModList::unipoly: -- Message text not found -- ({-I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, <<7973>>, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1})

Interrupt>
```

---

Personally I'd just call PARI via some python bridge.

```
GaussianIntegerQ[n_] := AllTrue[ReIm[n], IntegerQ]
DiscreteLog[n_Integer, pr_Integer, 
  p_Integer /; PrimeQ[p] && Mod[p, 4] == 1] := 
 ExternalEvaluate["Python", 
  TemplateApply[
   "import cypari2;pari=cypari2.Pari();Mod=pari.Mod;int(pari.znlog(\
Mod(`n`,`p`),Mod(`pr`,`p`)))", <|"n" -> n, "pr" -> pr, "p" -> p|>]]
DiscreteLog[n_Integer, p_Integer /; PrimeQ[p] && Mod[p, 4] == 1] := 
 DiscreteLog[n, PrimitiveRoot[p], p]
DiscreteLog[n_ /; GaussianIntegerQ[n], pr_ /; GaussianIntegerQ[pr], 
  p_Integer /; PrimeQ[p] && Mod[p, 4] == 3] := 
 ExternalEvaluate["Python", TemplateApply["
import cypari2
pari=cypari2.Pari()
p=`p`
ii=pari.ffgen(pari.Mod(pari('x^2=1'),p))
n=`na`+`nb`*ii
pr=`pra`+`prb`*ii
int(pari.fflog(n,pr))",
   With[{nn = ReIm@n, prr = ReIm@pr}, <|"na" -> nn[[1]], 
     "nb" -> nn[[2]], "pra" -> prr[[1]], "prb" -> prr[[2]], 
     "p" -> p|>]]]
GFp2PrimitiveRoot[p_Integer /; PrimeQ[p] && Mod[p, 4] == 3] := 
 ToExpression[ExternalEvaluate["Python", TemplateApply["
import cypari2
pari=cypari2.Pari()
ii=pari.ffgen(pari.Mod(pari('x^2+1'),`p`))
str(pari.ffprimroot(ii))", <|"p" -> p|>]]] /. x -> I
DiscreteLog[n_ /; GaussianIntegerQ[n], 
  p_Integer /; PrimeQ[p] && Mod[p, 4] == 3] := 
 ExternalEvaluate["Python", TemplateApply["
import cypari2
pari=cypari2.Pari()
ii=pari.ffgen(pari.Mod(pari('x^2+1'),`p`))
n=`na`+`nb`*ii
pr=pari.ffprimroot(ii)
int(pari.fflog(n,pr))", 
   With[{nn = ReIm@n}, <|"na" -> nn[[1]], "nb" -> nn[[2]], 
     "p" -> p|>]]]
```

Some tests:

```
p = 2^61 - 1;
pr = GFp2PrimitiveRoot[2^61 - 1];
logx = DiscreteLog[I, p]; (*8192 divides logx*)
y = PowerMod[pr, logx/8192, p]
```

This gives `-782078743845564464 + 729159760183691423 I` in less than 1 second. To verity, `PowerMod[y, 8192, p]` gives `I`.