# How to solve equations in Gaussian integers modulo p efficiently

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory, big-numbers

This question is related to my previous question which can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135575/how-to-solve-equations-in-gaussian-integers-modulo-p?answertab=oldest#tab-top). Calling the function

```
sols1 = gaussianPowerModList[I, 8192, 18446744069414584321];]
```

runs out of memory after more than 10 hours of execution.

Is there any way it can be computed more efficiently?